# Mongoose insertMany function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently working on a data import function for mongodb

It look something like this

*Note : the data using for importing is grabbing from an temporary collection in database and massaged before the insertion*

```
var Member = require('MemberModel'); //nodejs Mongoose npm
var arr = [{
    'memberNo': 'M001',
    'name': 'member 1'
}, ...];

Member.insertMany(arr, {ordered:false}, function(err, res){
    arr.forEach(function(item){
        //check exist in res using memberNo
    })
});
```

Currently, after the `insertMany`, I'll use looping to check whether the record in the array has been insert to database or not, and last, display which record(s) that failed to be insert deal to validation or something else.

This method is fairly inefficient when dealing with large amount of data.

It there any better way to do this ? or there is some `options` that i missed out from `Mongoose`.

Any help to this will be appreciated.

Comment: are you importing from file or rest endpoint?

Comment: the data is grabbing out from the db and massage before the insertion, all process within the server

Comment: had a look at the Bulk operations in mongo? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-bulk/

Comment: If you want to check your record, it will be a good idea to do before it is inserted into the database. If you want to know which documents have validation error during the process, you can use `err ` from `insertMany`.